# use parameter in html tag on sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert a parameter (@ERROR_MSG) in the html tag (@body=), how can I do that?

```
DECLARE  @ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @ERROR_MSG = ''
SET @ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='my email',
@body= '<html><body><p>Hi,</p><p>Please check again file.</p><p>Thank you.</p></body></html>'
@body_format = 'HTML',
@subject ='Error when import file into database'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
DECLARE  @ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @ERROR_MSG = ''
SET @ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='my email',
@body= '<html><body><p>Hi,</p><p>Please check again file.</p><p>'+@ERROR_MSG+'</p><p>Thank you.</p></body></html>'
@body_format = 'HTML',
@subject ='Error when import file into database'
```

Comment: Thanks NickyvV

I used as you , but not OK




  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c2kLj.png

Answer (score 0):

Following up on NickyvV, the solution might be to first declare a variable for the @body, set its' value and then use it in the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure:

```
DECLARE  @ERROR_MSG VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @ERROR_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()

DECLARE @BodyWithError VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @BodyWithError = '<html><body><p>Hi,</p><p>Please check again file.</p><p>'+@ERROR_MSG+'</p><p>Thank you.</p></body></html>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='my email',
@body= @BodyWithError,
@body_format = 'HTML',
@subject ='Error when import file into database'
```